# geolocalization received of streaming service of twitter is null

Tags: twitter-oauth

I am trying to filter the tweets coming from my country, with the word "andino", the tweets  will come from Colombia. But in the information the tweets that I receive with the keys of "coordinates", "place" are null. How can I get the geolocation of the tweets?

With the current code, I made the change to filter the tweets with the word "andino", making the following change:

line 11

https://github.com/UsabilityEtc/twitter-geo-server-js/blob/master/js/twitter-connection.js

```
  { track: "andino" }
```

instead of:

```
 { locations: boundingBox },
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems not all the tweets have their geolocation information publicly accessible, so it's normal that most of them are null.